# Laravel v5.7 belongs to doesn't return the model after install Laravel Passport v7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My code was working fine. After installing Laravel Passport v7 (latest version of this writing of the post and btw I am using Laravel v5.7 also the latest version) my code it's not working anymore. When i try to run `$user->role->id` i am getting an error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

That's because my `$user->role` it is not returning the Role model object, but instead it is returning `null` and before install Laravel Passport it was returning the Role model. I don't know if there are any connections, but I don't want to change my entire code, because of that. Even I tried to write inside my User model `return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');`, but this is not working as well.

here is my code:
User model:

```
namespace App;

use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Role mode:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

User table schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email', 250)->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('phone', 11)->nullable();
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

role table schema:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

HomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();

        $products = new Product;

        // here i am getting the error
        if ($user->role_id > 2) {
            $products = Product::where('name', '!=', NULL)->latest()->paginate(6);
        } else {
            $products = $products->getApprovedAndUntaken();
        }

        return view('welcome', compact('products'));
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: where u get error  'id' of non-object ?

Comment: what query are you using to access the data?

Comment: at which point your error message got thrown?

Comment: I the HomeController i have this code `if ($user->role->id > 2)` and there I am getting this error

Comment: please post the code related to that. (HomeController)

Comment: I also have found that all my code where i have a belongsTo methods are NOT working, because i can simple say `$user->role_id` and this will work, but when i get other error at `$achievement->credit->credits;` saying ***Trying to get property 'credits' of non-object*** and i dont get why as it was working fine :(

Comment: please go and check up if Auth::user() returns the correct user, or if the auth method got changed by implementing passport

Comment: @Traxstar, I edited the post and added my HomeController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181668/discussion-between-dimitar-and-traxstar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the mistake is related to a wrong configured Auth Guard within `config/auth.php`.

Go and check if your array looks like the following after you have installed passport:

*config/auth.php*

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport', // Passport goes here
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Any time you want to access a related object you should access it like

```
$user->object()
```

and not

```
$user->object
```

Please let me now if this was working for you!

Answer (score 0):

use `with` method to get the join data

```
$products = Product::where('name', '!=', NULL)->with('role')->get()->paginate(6);
```

Comment: If the error is on running an `if` on `user->role_id > 2` that precedes the `Product::where()` then how does this help?